# How to display Japanese characters passed through an ajax query on a jsp page

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have a .jsp page and that makes an ajax request to a different .jsp page. The query parameter contains Japanese characters. I have confirmed by looking at the request that the characters are getting passed correctly. However the string is not received correctly on the other side.

Here are the files:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            url = "ajaxHandler.jsp";
            $.ajax({ 
                type : "GET",
                url : url,
                data: {  parameter : "\u306f" },
                dataType : "html", //expect html to be returned
                success : function(response) {
                    console.log("successful query");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
```

ajaxHandler.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%
    String val = request.getParameter("parameter");
%>
<br>
<%=val %>
```

When I hit the url "https:.../ajaxHandler.jsp?parameter=%E3%81%AF",  a completely different character is displayed.

I suspect that there is an issue with the character encoding for the page. I have tried with "utf-8" and now with "shift-jis" , but still I cannot get the string displayed.

So I want to know basically why do we specify the charset and how is it used here. Also please tell how can I get the string.

PS: "\u306f" is an actual japanese character thats getting displayed in eclipse and not its unicode as here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit ***server.xml*** file, located in tomcat ***conf*** folder.

according to the relevant connector specify `URIEncoding` as **UTF-8**

For instance, I am using `https` connector, so the connector configuration in the `server.xml` looks like that:

[image]

As you have updated `server.xml`, restart your Tomcat.

That's it.